# Using a typename nested in a template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, nested, typename

This is a mouthful, so here's a piece of code as an example:

```
template<typename T>
void foo(const T& a, typename T::value_type::value_type b) { }

std::vector<std::vector<int>> vec;
foo(vec, 4); // Error, can't specialize function template
```

This compiles and runs correctly using gcc. It doesn't compile using Visual Studio 2010, for the reason commented above. However, if the final `value_type` is prefixed with the `template` keyword, it will compile and run correctly. I have a few guesses as to why, but can't find the relevant section of the standard.

```
template<typename T>
void foo(const T& a, typename T::value_type::template value_type b) { }

std::vector<std::vector<int>> vec;
foo(vec, 4); // Compiles and runs correctly with Visual Studio 2010
```

I'm aware that the above usage of `template` is a Visual Studio extension, but what does the standard say about using types like this? Is gcc's acceptance of the code also an extension, or is this a deficiency on Visual Studio's part?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is absolutely a deficiency on VC++ 2010's part – `std::vector<int>::value_type` is a type, not a template, and should not be decorated as such. In fact, use of that syntax in this context *should* cause a compiler error.

Supporting evidence is that the following does compile (as it should):

```
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
void foo(T const& a)
{
    typename T::value_type::value_type bar = a.at(0).at(0);
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> vec;
    foo(vec);
}
```

and the following doesn't (as it shouldn't):

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T const& a)
{
    typename T::value_type::template value_type bar = a.at(0).at(0);
}
```

The resulting error being

> error C2903: `'value_type'` : symbol is neither a class template nor a function template

I recommend opening a bug report on [MS Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/) and posting the link back here so we can vote it up.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that shortly. Aside from the incorrect usage of `template`, though, is the code standard conformant?

Comment: The issue is materially equivalent to ["Template function returning dependent type fails to compile"](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/251698/template-function-returning-dependent-type-fails-to-compile) which was closed as "Won't Fix."  That was over four years ago, though, and it's probably worthwhile to open a new bug on Connect.

Comment: @dauphic : Yes, the code you showed that compiles for GCC is perfectly conformant (aside from the two consecutive `>`s when declaring `vec`, which is only conformant for C++0x, not C++03).

Comment: I'm unable to sign in to Connect right now; maybe it's down. If someone else wants to open a bug report, go for it, otherwise I'll make a note and try it later.